# Getting Last Entity with more than one Relation in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am trying to get the latest entity of mine that has more than one Image Entity as a OneToMany connection.

The Code:

```
$qb->select("a")->from("album","a");
$qb->having("count(a.images) > 0");
$qb->orderBy("a.id","DESC");
$qb->setMaxResults(1);
```

The Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT a FROM Album a HAVING count(a.images) > 0 ORDER BY a.id DESC' in ... /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41 Stack trace:...

I fount out that the error is in the second line and I also tried `$qb->where("count(a.images) > 0")`

I hope you can help me. If you need any further Infos, pls let me know.

**Edit:**

I also tried adding an groupBy Statement and joing the Images to the Album now

```
$qb->select("a")->from("album","a")->join("a.images","i");
$qb->groupBy("a.id")->having("count(a.images) > 0");
$qb->orderBy("a.id","DESC");
$qb->setMaxResults(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just found out the answer:

```
$qb->select("a")->from("album","a")->join("a.images","i");
$qb->groupBy("a.id")->having("count(i.id) > 0");
$qb->orderBy("a.id","DESC");
$qb->setMaxResults(1);
```

important to use `i.id` not `a.images`!